# Magento Customer Attribute Value Multi Website Issue

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, customer-attribute, unique-constraint

I have multi website setup and,
I have create one Custom Customer Attribute named "mobile_number", that shows on create account form at frontend.
Now the issue is while creating customer in one website and customer registers with "123" mobile_number and then again if I create the customer with same mobile_number in second website then it gives me error of The value of the "Mobile Number" attribute isn't unique. Set a unique value and try again.

Basically It has to be allow to use same mobile_number in both websites.

Comment: Hello there, could you please clarify few things for me? First, does it work without the attribute "mobile_number"? Second, could you please let me know your configuration for customer account sharing (Stores --> Configuration --> Customers --> Customer Configuration)? And last, What are the properties of the attribute "mobile_number"?